# Change Menu Order

Tags: menus, order

I have read a post attempting to assist someone to reorder their menus in Word Press.

I am new to all of this and immediately find great frustration.

The advice given herein does not match what I am seeing on the platform. As an immediate example, a new user asks how to reorder menus and is answered that they may go into "Appearance," then "Menus" and then 'simply' drag and reposition them in the order they see fit.

However, when I do this there is no apparent drag functionality.

The appearance of the page is grey and dull with little checkmark boxes next to the menus I attempted to create. What am I missing?!

I really wish these platforms were more intuitive and user-friendly...

Answer (score 0):

If it's greyed out it's because you haven't created a menu yet. Once you give it a name and save it, you should be able to add pages and links to your menu.

Once you have links/pages, you can begin to sort the menu by dragging them up or down.